# Request for clarification about OOP procedure in PHP

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I am trying to write the following code in PHP

```
class A {
 protected static $comment = "I am A" ;
 public static function getComment () {
  return self :: $comment; 
 }
}

class B extends A {
 protected static $comment = "I am B" ;
}

echo B::getComment () ; // echoes "I am A"
```

Shouldn't it return `I am B` ? In oop PHP does not the child overwrite the parent? Thank you  for the clarifications.

== EDIT ==

Also my question is what is the difference then between static and instance because in instance it works:

```
class A {
    protected $comment = "I am A" ;

    public function getComment () {
        return $this -> comment ;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $comment = "I am B" ;
}

$B=new B ;

echo $B->getComment();
```

Comment: Take a look at this post:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280001/protected-static-member-variables][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280001/protected-static-member-variables

Comment: Awesome! I did not know that late static binding thing -- it is really useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called "late static binding", and is [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

The short version is that in order to get static variables working the way you want them to, you need to use `static::` instead of `self::`.

Note: this only works in PHP 5.3 and greater.

Comment: Thank you sir I will accept yours as the answer as soon as my very tiny reputation allows me to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it overwrite it but in your case you did not overwriting `getComment` method of `parent class.`

if you try

```
class B extends A {
 protected static $comment = "I am B" ;
 public static function getComment () {
  return self :: $comment; 
 }
}
```

then it will display `I am B`.

what actually you are doing is calling `getComment` method of `b class` which is not exists in `child class` so it **bubble up** to `parent class` method and display result.

Comment: But why does it work in an instance context, for ex:
class A {
 protected $comment = "I am A" ;

 public function getComment () {
  return $this -> comment ;
 }
}

class B extends A {
 protected $comment = "I am B" ;
}

$B=new B ;

echo $B->getComment(); // echo I am B

Comment: @user28490 look your tiny reputation has increase little...lol

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LATE STATIC BINDING

```
class A {
 protected static $comment = "I am A" ;
 public static function getComment () {
  return static :: $comment; 
 }
}

class B extends A {
 protected static $comment = "I am B" ;
}

echo B::getComment () ; // echoes "I am A"
```

I hope this make some sense