# Can't access value of protected static variable php 7.0.13

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to implement a **DataTable** class in php which will be basically a table to contain data just like an sql table and will be made of **array()**

The class is defined as followed:

```
class DataTable{

            protected static $tabela; // table
            //columns and strips, each column point to a strip
            public function __construct($colunas, $faixas) {

                $this->tabela = array();
                $this->constroiDt($colunas, $faixas); //builds the table

            }

            public function getRows($where){
                // todo
            }

            public static function getTabela(){
                return $this->tabela;
            }

            private function constroiDt($colunas, $faixas){
                if(count($colunas)!= count($faixas)){
                    $this->tabela = null;
                    return;
                }

                $i=0;
                foreach($colunas as $cl){
                    $this->tabela = array_merge($this->tabela, array($cl => $faixas[$i]));
                    $i += $i + 1;
                }
                // the result will be an array like ('col1' => ('val1','val2'), 'col2' => ('val1','val2'))
                // if I want to access a value, just type array['col1'][0] for example

            }
        }
```

Outside of the class function, when I create an example DT and try to access it, it seems that will work:

```
$columns = array("name", "age");
$strips = array(array("someone","another person"),array("20","30"));
$dt1 = new DataTable($columns, $strips);
var_dump($dt1); // will print:
// object(DataTable)#1 (1) { ["tabela"]=> array(2) { ["nome"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "fulano" [1]=> string(7) "ciclano" } ["idade"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(2) "30" } } }
```

But then I add `echo "--- " . $dt1::getTabela()['nome'][0];`

**It doesn't even print the ---**. `var_dump($dt1::getTabela())` and `var_dump($dt1->getTabela())` also is blank. What is being missed here? Tried also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280928/2414842) but didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$this` in a static function / for static properties as there is not necessarily an object context to use.

Instead, you should use `self::$tabela` everywhere instead.

Or change your variable (and the related methods...) to a "normal" protected property:

```
protected $tabela;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing static variables with non static accesors

i just put your code and i got a lot of errors/notices

```
NOTICE Accessing static property DataTable::$tabela as non static on line number 10

NOTICE Accessing static property DataTable::$tabela as non static on line number 31

NOTICE Accessing static property DataTable::$tabela as non static on line number 31

NOTICE Accessing static property DataTable::$tabela as non static on line number 31

NOTICE Accessing static property DataTable::$tabela as non static on line number 31
object(DataTable)#1 (1) { ["tabela"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "someone" [1]=> string(14) "another person" } ["age"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(2) "30" } } } 
FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code:20 Stack trace: #0 /home/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5) : eval()'d code(44): DataTable::getTabela() #1 /home/phptest/public_html/code.php70(5): eval() #2 {main} thrown on line number 20
```